# Turkey e visa; is it valid for two trips?

Tags: visas

I am applying for an e-visa from Turkey (since I have a 2 year duration German tourist visa). The Turkish visa says validity is 6 months and 90 days stay for each trip.

The point that I am unclear about is whether I can use this e-visa on more than one trip? I keep connecting on flights via Istanbul so I may other future opportunities to land in Turkey.

Any help?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: In that case your evisa will be single entry. Everytime you visit again you have to get a new eVisa. https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/

Answer (score 1):

Turkey issues multiple entry E-visas.

https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/

If your visa is multiple entry (according to description you have provided, it is), you can enter multiple times in turkey.

6 months, 90 days means that you can stay upto 90 days on each entry for the validity mentioned.

**Update:** Since you are an Indian citizen, you are not eligible for multiple entry e-Visa.

Comment: That site says that only some nationalities get a multiple entry e-visa.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. Only limited counties are given multiple entry e-visa

Comment: More details here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Turkey#e-Visa